# How to compare Enum instances in Rust

Tags: rust, enums, equality

Hey I'm learning rust and trying to figure out why I can't directly compare two instances of a very simple Enum, I've tried using `matches!` (doesn't work) and `#[derive(Eq)]` (just forwards the problem to the `impl`

Here's a snippet demonstrating my issue, and it's output.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MyEnum {
    Enum1,
    Enum2,
    Enum3
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ThingEnum {
    NoOp,
    Enum(MyEnum)
}

pub fn test_enum_equate() {
    let mut enum1 = Vec::new();
    enum1.push(MyEnum::Enum1);
    enum1.push(MyEnum::Enum2);
    enum1.push(MyEnum::Enum3);

    let mut expr = vec![
        ThingEnum::NoOp,
        ThingEnum::Enum(MyEnum::Enum1),
        ThingEnum::Enum(MyEnum::Enum2),
        ThingEnum::NoOp,
        ThingEnum::Enum(MyEnum::Enum3)
    ];

    for myenum in enum1.iter() {
        for entry in expr.iter() {
            match entry {
                ThingEnum::NoOp => continue,
                ThingEnum::Enum(en) => {
                    // Check if they are the same
                    println!("matches!({:?}, {:?}) = {}",
                        myenum, en, matches!(myenum, en)
                    );
                    // Need to implement partial eq, WHY?
                    // println!("{:?} == {:?} -> {}",
                    //     myenum, en, myenum == en
                    // );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
matches!(Enum1, Enum1) = true
matches!(Enum1, Enum2) = true
matches!(Enum1, Enum3) = true
matches!(Enum2, Enum1) = true
matches!(Enum2, Enum2) = true
matches!(Enum2, Enum3) = true
matches!(Enum3, Enum1) = true
matches!(Enum3, Enum2) = true
matches!(Enum3, Enum3) = true
```

Which isn't the desired effect.

If I just used numbers or strings, this would work fine, but I feel like the usefulness of an Enum should be that there is no associated value, so why is this so difficult to make work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Rust equality comes in two forms, `PartialEq` and `Eq`. Every `Eq` is also `PartialEq`, but the reverse is not true. Specifically, `PartialEq` only requires that the operation be a [partial equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_equivalence_relation), while `Eq` makes the stronger guarantee that the relation is an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation).

A good example of types which are `PartialEq` but not `Eq` are the floating-point types `f32` and `f64`, both of which have a special NaN value which is not equal to itself. In data structures like hashmaps and binary trees, having a value that is not equal to itself is disastrous, so data structures like those require a type that is `Eq`, while `f32` is only `PartialEq`. Go try to make a `HashSet<f32>`. You'll run into some compiler errors pretty quick.

In your case, however, you don't really need to worry about any of this. Since your type is a simple enum, you can simply derive *both* `PartialEq` and `Eq`.

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum MyEnum { ... }
```

Then `==` will work exactly as you'd like it to.

Comment: I thought I tried this, guess I didn't derive both, thanks!